# Add target to swift package

Tags: ios, swift, package, swiftpm

I hope to ask this correctly, but let me know if clarification is needed.

I developed a standalone app that displays data to the user (not important). I have a swift package that I would like to add this app (target) too, so that the package can be added from swiftPM and then all the user has to do is call the initializer of this app that I created. The swift package is ready and the standalone app is completed. I'm just not sure how to add this app's target to the package and if there is anything I need to do to convert the standalone app so that it works in the package.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Any guidance or tutorials on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Move you standalone app code base in separate package/library and use in both your app and your main package

Comment: What if I want to add it to the existing package as another target?

Comment: As far i know swift package can only add another package only